# Need help w/ formatting on github

Tags: github

I'm new to programming and starting to put some of my projects into github so that I have something to show employers. I copied and pasted code from one of my first projects I did last summer, but when looking at the page (https://github.com/allisonecrenshaw/world_cup_cosc1336), all the comment sections from my code (# symbol since this one was written in my class that used Python) have giant writing. I'm guessing that usign # in github is for titles rather than comments, so I'm a little lost on how I should really be putting my programs into github so that it's formatted in whatever way is standard for the site. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You should post that https://github.community/

Answer (score 1):

The file is in markdown language. For examples see:
https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet

In your case use three backticks at the start and end of your code (including the comments).

So:

````
```
# comment
some code
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Any file named README.md will be interpreted as a [Markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/cheat-sheet/) file in github (and many other source code viewers.) Rename the file to have a python extension (and possibly create a new README.md file with explanations) and it should solve the problem.

Comment: So I currently have it written as american_football_cosc1336/README.md, what should replace the README.md?

Comment: Any filename, really. It looks like a python script, and python files end in .py, so `code.py` or `my_project.py` or `anything_really.py` should work. :) I'll add that you can totally have code in markdown files, like Araldo's response shows. So if you really want a Read-me type file with code in it, that's the way to go. But code itself shouldn't be saved as Markdown.